# Why doesn't QTCreator warn me if an emplace_back is completely wrong?

Tags: c++, c++11, qt-creator, static-analysis

Let's say I have this vector of pairs of numbers:

```
std::vector<std::pair<ulong, ulong>> uniquePairs;
```

If I do:

```
uniquePairs.emplace_back("literal garbage data");
```

It doesn't yell at me. Shouldn't something be screaming at me that this code is horribly, completely wrong? There are no warnings from the linter at all.

Of course, it fails when I go to actually compile with GCC.

Comment: That would require your background code analyser to perform an enormous amount of work for template instantiation and alike. This is hard because of the level of indirection - you're perfect forwarding the arguments of `emplace_back`.

Comment: Which version? With Clang Code Model?

Comment: The signature of the emplace back is a function that takes **anything**.  It's hard to say that your input would then be bad.

Comment: @Fureeish Could you explain a bit more? What is the main difference between checking if the arguments are right in this case, vs. for some other function? Why would emplace_back be more work?

Comment: @NathanOliver Why is it "anything"? If I'm emplace_back'ing onto a ```std::vector<std::pair<ulong,ulong>>``` than in this case, doesn't that narrow down "anything" to the arguments needed to construct a ```std::pair<ulong, ulong>```?

Comment: `std::vector::emplace_back` takes a *parameter pack*, i.e., `template <typeneme... Types> void emplace_back(Types&&... types) { ... }`. Then it *perfect forwards them* to *construct* the `value_type` (`std::pair<ulong, ulong>`) inside the vector. To work it has to: **1)** instantiate the `emplace_back` function from your signature (`const char[21]`), **2)** instantiate `std::forward` with the same thing, **3)** check if `value_type` *can be constructed* with that result. This *may* be **a lot of** work. Not necessarily here, but in general case, things may end up cascading much much deeper.

Comment: And it would *have to **repeat*** this whole process for every `empalce_back` call you make. Even if your `"literals"` were to be just 1 `char`acter off. Those are differeny types when passed by reference. EDIT: "*doesn't that narrow down "anything" to the arguments needed to construct [...]*" - this case is pretty trivial, despire the amount of work I just explained above. General cases are usually mroe complex (longer and harder to smoothly check). They just don't implement it instead of implementing it just for the most basic use cases.

Comment: @Fureeish Thanks for the insight. It is unfortunate though! At least the compiler isn't cryptic with the failure so that's a win. If you want you can toss that full explanation in an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I do:
>
> ```
> uniquePairs.emplace_back("literal garbage data");
> ```
>
> It doesn't yell at me.

Because it *doesn't check for correctness of (execution of) such statement*.

---

The real question, then, is - **why it doesn't do so?**

The answer is: because that's usually *a **lot** of work*. Let's examine this very case:

```
uniquePairs.emplace_back("literal garbage data");
```

attempts to call `template< class... Args > reference emplace_back( Args&&... args )`, where `Args` is a *parameter pack* consisting of one type - `const char[21]`. Keep in mind that `"c-string literals"` have distinct types for every length of the literal. This is **problem #1**.

#### Problem #1:

Instantiating `emplace_back`s for all the types you're calling with it. It's not *that* much work, but it may add up afterwards.

Successful instantiation of said function template results in (by definition of the function), perfect forwarding, i.e., **problem #2**.

#### Problem #2:

Calling (instantiating) `std::forward`. This is just repeating **problem #1**, but in another scope. Not great, not terrible.

#### Problem #3:

After we already instantiated (in the background, without full intent of compilation) some function templates, we now need to check if *perfectly forwarded arguments for `emplace_back` **can construct** a `value_type` of your `std::vector`*.

Your `value_type` is `std::pair<ulong, ulong>`. Obviously, `const char[21]` cannot do that. Your IDE can now scream at you.

---

This is a pretty trivial case, but notice how much work had to be done at the first place. Now imagine that you are perfect forwarding something else. More arguments. More calls. More background instantiations.

Background code sanitisers should not interrupt your work. They also should (hopefully) give you reliable hints in a reasonable time fashion. This very feature may be quite trivial (your case) or *very complicated*. The simples answer is just to not attempt to accomplish such tasks.

#### Bonus:

Why, then, if you `push_back("literal garbage data")`, the IDE usually yells at you?

Because `push_back`'s signature takes either `const T&` or `T&&` for `std::vector<T>`. It's pretty trivial to see that `const char[21]` is **not** a `std::pair<ulong, ulong>` (neither is *convertible* to one). No instantiations needed (provided that the instantiation of your `vector` was already done at the background. If not, add another problem to both cases). Not a lof of work. Easy to compute, easy to warn about.